Path of PATH, does it make a difference?
I think this is a windows question, but in my computer, if I look up the environment variables, I see only a Path variable and not a PATH variable. is there a difference between these two, or are environment variables case-independent?

Windows (7, 10, 11) environment variables are case insensitive, so you can use PATH and Path interchangeably
